# Replacing "If" with "When" in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am having trouble converting an `if` expression into a `when` expression in kotlin. My If code is as followed:

```
fun main() {
    var cardPoints = 7_000


    val cardLevel: String = if (cardPoints >= 0 && cardPoints < 1000) {
        "pearl"
    } else if (cardPoints >= 1000 && cardPoints < 5_000) {
        "silver"
    } else if (cardPoints >= 5_000 && cardPoints < 10_000) {
        "gold"
    } else {
        "platinum"
    }

    val plural = if(cardPoints > 1 || cardPoints == 0) "s" else ""
    println("You have $cardPoints point$plural and are at the $cardLevel level.")
}
```

However, I must now convert it into a "When" expression (preferably in ranges), this is what I have so far:

```
fun main() {
    var cardPoints = 7_000

    val cardLevel: String = when {
        cardPoints >= 0 && cardPoints < 1000 -> "pearl"

        cardPoints >= 1000 && cardPoints < 5_000 -> "silver"

        cardPoints >= 5_000 && cardPoints < 10_000 -> "gold"
        else -> "platinum"

    }
    val plural = if(cardPoints > 1 || cardPoints == 0) "s" else ""
    println("You have $cardPoints point$plural and are at the $cardLevel level.")
}
```

I am unsure on what else needs to be tweaked or if I am missing something entirely. I would be thankful for any help and suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Not as much an answer but a tip: Instead of manually converting, if you are using Android Studio or IntelliJ there is an automatic way. 
You can move your cursor on `if`, press Alt+Enter and select "Replace if with when". This way has the benefit that it prevents errors that could potentially happen when manually converting code.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`range`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html) with an `in` operator to solve the problem.

```
var cardPoints = 7000
val cardLevel: String = when {
    cardPoints in 0..999 -> "pearl"

    cardPoints in 1000..4999 -> "silver"

    cardPoints in 5000..9999 -> "gold"

    else -> "platinum"

}
```

Comment: but ranges should end with `999`, `4999` and `9999`, right?

Comment: @tpschmidt You're correct. I fixed the answer. Thanks.

Comment: hmm I tried this method of using in  but unfortunately, I receive an error: Unresolved reference: cardPoints?

Comment: I took the relevant snippet from the original question. Define the variable before the `when` expression.

Comment: It finally worked! To both tpschmidt and @AndrejH  Thank you for the help :) I was receiving the error i mentioned above because the end of the ranges were off.

Answer (score 2):

you can use also

```
fun main () {
    var cardPoints = 7_000

    val cardLevel: String = when(cardPoints) {
        in 0..1000 -> "pearl"
        in 1000..5000 -> "silver"
        in 5000..10000 -> "gold"
        else -> "platinum"
    }

    val plural = if(cardPoints > 1 || cardPoints == 0) "s" else ""
    println("You have $cardPoints point$plural and are at the $cardLevel level.")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler (and more efficient) approach: just omit the range and take advantage of the order of `when`-evaluation:

```kotlin
when {
  cardPoints < 0 -> error("this probably shouldn't be platinum, right?")
  cardPoints < 1000 -> "pearl"
  cardPoints < 5000 -> "silver"
  cardPoints < 10000 -> "gold"
  else -> "platinum"
}
```

This also holds true of course for your `if` itself:

```kotlin
if (points < 0) error("not platinum, right?")
else if (points < 1000) "pearl"
else if (points < 5000) "silver"
else if (points < 10000) "gold"
else "platinum"
```

In both cases you do not have to repeat, what was already evaluated one step earlier, e.g. if it isn't lower than 0, the next condition doesn't need to repeat `>= 0`, because we already know it isn't `< 0` and it can only be `>= 0` at the next point. Same if it is not lower than 1000, the next condition doesn't need to repeat, that it is `>= 1000`. If you will, you can simplify each `if (x) else if (!x && y)` to `if (x) else if (y)`...

If you use ranges, just keep in mind that it will be much slower (on my machine with a factor of ~3-4), which of course you can ignore, if performance is not an issue.

If my assumption that `< 0` is not platinum is wrong, then I would probably just return `"platinum"` there as well instead of using ranges.